# sql Database to save different contact details for a message sending site

Tags: sql, database, save, contacts

I am working for a project to create a database for saving different persons contact details in SQL.
For example,
**X person saves 10 contacts, Y persons save 15 contacts, z persons save 20 contacts and so on.
I cant create separate tables to save contacts of x,y,z and so on. But i just want to know the alternative method to do that. Is there any easy method to save different contacts and is there any easy method to retrieve it.**
I'm just a student, I don't know much about sql and don't have much experience in this. So I need your help to know much about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need one table of contacts, with a column of user ID.

Another Table of Users (Persons) and a FK between them.

This is better.

Comment: thanks for your response...
i created a table "members" with id and mobile no as PK,
ID  Name  Mobno
________________
1   john  9999999999
2   sam   8888888888

then i saved their contacts in the table "contacts" with id and mobieno as PK.
ID   Name   Mobileno
______________________
1    gem    89898989
1    tim    90909090
1    sam    8888888888
2    tim    90909090
2    david  55445544
Here john save a contact called david, now i want to send a request to sam saying that "do u know david with 55445544 mobileno."

How to do that dude?

Comment: The id is enough for FK
SELECT * from tblContacts T, Person P where T.PersonID = P.PersonID and P.Name = 'David' (you don't need and P.Phone = '12323232') 
There is a better way to "Write" it using a JOIN (you are joining the tables on ID column).

Comment: ACtually - that will give you all david's contacts, you need to do it for sam's id and see if david is one of his contacts.